# OllyDbg 2.01 Run Trace "Skip selection option"

Tags: ollydbg

In OllyDbg 1.10 it was possible to skip some parts of code when starting run trace(just example):

[image]

So when there is some heavy code it was possible to skip to trace only some useful information.

I cannot find same "Run trace -> Skip selection from run trace" option in OllyDbg 2.01. I cannot find any info on that on the internet too. Does it mean there is no such option in the newer version of the software? How is this possible at all?

I need to exclude some heavy code that is always present in the run trace, but I don't need it, and I cannot interact with the application when it records all those lines.

**update**

There is an answer that shows some workaround, but this is not exactly what 1.10 has, because in 1.10 you can select the code and just skip it. So I just want confirmation if this functionality was removed from the new version of OllyDbg, or there is some other (but also comfortable, not manual) way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `CTRL + P` protocol only the following EIP ranges

Add the ranges above and below the block to be skipped

the skipped block !

[image]

edit

no there doesn't seem to be any skip feature looking inside plugin.h i see only MAX 64 (NRTPROT) ranges can be protocolled  and the address is defined in t_range the code below can automate putting one range automatically into the dialog box for subsequent ranges you may need to implement logic that checks if selection is within an earlier block or not if yes split that block into pieces   code below compilable in vc++ 2010 express

```
#define UNICODE
#define _CHAR_UNSIGNED
#include <windows.h>
#include "plugin.h"
#pragma comment(lib,"ollydbg.lib")
//grab the plugin.h and ollydbg.lib from visual c folder in plugin kit and put them along
//this cpp file open vs2k10 express ->new -> project from existing code -> Dll ->finish
// open project properties and disable INCREMENTAL save solution and quit gui
// open a vs2k10 command prompt and do msbuild /p:configuration=Release 
BOOL WINAPI DllEntryPoint( HINSTANCE,DWORD,LPVOID ) { return 1; };
int Skiprangefromrtprot( t_table *pt, wchar_t *name, ulong index, int mode ) {
    if (mode==MENU_VERIFY) { return MENU_NORMAL;
    } else if ( mode==MENU_EXECUTE) {
        Resumeallthreads();
        t_dump *cpudump = Getcpudisasmdump();
        ulong startsel = cpudump->sel0;
        ulong endsel = cpudump->sel1;
        t_module *curmod = Findmodule(startsel);
        if(curmod != 0) {
            Addprotocolrange(curmod->base,startsel);
            Addprotocolrange(endsel,(curmod->base + curmod->size));
        }
        Suspendallthreads();
        return MENU_NOREDRAW;
    } else {
        return MENU_ABSENT;
    }
};
t_menu disasmmenu[] = {
    { L"|SkipFromRunTrace", NULL,K_NONE, Skiprangefromrtprot, NULL, 0 },
    { NULL, NULL,K_NONE, NULL, NULL, 0 }
};
extc int __cdecl ODBG2_Pluginquery( int ollydbgversion, ulong *features,
    wchar_t pluginname[SHORTNAME], wchar_t pluginversion[SHORTNAME] ) {
        if (ollydbgversion<201)
            return 0;
        wcscpy_s( pluginname, SHORTNAME,L"SkipFromRunTrace" );
        wcscpy_s( pluginversion,SHORTNAME, L"2.00.01" );
        return PLUGIN_VERSION;
};
extc t_menu * __cdecl ODBG2_Pluginmenu( wchar_t *type ) {
    if (wcscmp(type,PWM_DISASM)==0)
        return disasmmenu;
    return NULL;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I found it yesterday on my own, but still there is no automatic way to do what I want. My intention is to add the whole module first, then when run trace is run, I see what parts I don't need and just skip them. Manually it takes time to put skipped parts to the range. I am thinking about maybe to write plugin which will do the job.

Comment: i am not sure if you can skip but you dont have to enter ranges manually select a block right click -> breakpoint -> add selection to protocol / add procedure to protocol

Comment: yes, but it adds only selected to the protocol, i need opposite. I need to track everything except some procedures which I want to select. It should have some option, like invert ranges or smth like that.