# Making plugins for Ollydbg 2

Tags: ollydbg, automation, plugin

I have been looking around for ways to make plugins in Ollydbg 2 and I haven't seen a good amount of information;I keep finding guides for Immunity Dbg or how to make plugins work.

I don't mind learning to make plugins but, there seems to be a very limited amount of information on the net for Ollydbg. Does anyone know where I can find some information on how to make plugins for Ollydbg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

complete src code and build instruction is available in this post for a sample plugin

[OllyDbg 2.01 Run Trace "Skip selection option"](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8290/ollydbg-2-01-run-trace-skip-selection-option/8292#8292)

Comment: I suppose that this is good as it gets. This debugger will be replacing them shortly. http://x64dbg.com/#start